# Computing the residues for $1 /( z^2\sin(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to find the residues for the function $1 / (z^2\sin (z))$. By expanding the function around the singularites I managed to find $\text{Res}(f;0) = 1/3!$. There is also a singularity at $z = n\pi$ where I know that $\text{Res}(f;n\pi) = (-1)^n / (n
\pi)^2$ but I dont know how to calculate the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singularities other than $0$ are all of a particularly simple type. $\sin z$ has a simple zero in $k\pi,\, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and the rest of the function is holomorphic there, so you can write

$$f(z) = \frac{1/z^2}{\sin z},$$

and since a function

$$\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$$

with holomorphic $g$ and $h$ has the residue

$$\frac{g(\zeta)}{h'(\zeta)}$$

in a simple zero $\zeta$ of $h$, we obtain

$$\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1/z^2}{\sin z}; k\pi \right) = \frac{1/(k\pi)^2}{\cos (k\pi)} = \frac{(-1)^k}{(k\pi)^2}$$

for $k\neq 0$.